# Python sends several emails when error occurs instead of one

Tags: python

I am still learning python and now my goal is to figure out how to send an email confirmation about finished jobs.
This is the python code that I wrote and it works fine (from my point of view) if there is no error, but when I, on purpose, made some errors within the code in order to see what kind of email notification I would receive, I get six email notifications.

Any idea how to fix this.

In the end, my goal/task here is to get just one email notification either for a successful job or occurred errors.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import smtplib
import logging
import logging.handlers
import numpy as np

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from datetime import datetime

logging.basicConfig(filename='history.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s :: %(levelname)s :: %(message)s')


SERVER = 'SQL_MYSERVER\DBO'
DATABASE = 'DBO'
DRIVER = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

# Read data from excel file
try:
    start_reading_file=datetime.now()
    df_sheet_name_b=pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\xxx123123\\OneDrive - Personal\\Desktop\\Folder1\\file.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
    end_reading_time=datetime.now()
    count_row=df_sheet_name_b.shape[0]
    time_reading_execution = end_reading_time - start_reading_file
    # Get the list of all column names from headers
    column_headers = list(df_sheet_name_b.columns.values)
    print("The Column Header :", column_headers)
    
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e)


try:
    # Select specific columns from the excel file
    columns_b=df_sheet_name_b[['header1','header2','header3','header4','header5','header6']]
    start_writing_data=datetime.now()
    df2.sample(n=100).to_sql('table_test', sql_engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=10000)
    count_rows_inserted=df2.shape[0]
    end_writing_data=datetime.now()
    writing_time_execution = end_writing_data - start_writing_data
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e)


# Send an email about time executions

try:
    sender = 'xxx123123@company.com'
    receivers = ['xxx123123@company.com']

    message = """From: From Person <xxx123123@company.com>
    To: To Person <xxx123123@company.com>
    Subject: Excel file read/write


    Reading file START TIME: """  + str(start_reading_file) + """\n
    Reading file END TIME: """  + str(end_reading_time) + """\n
    Reading execution time: """  + str(time_reading_execution) + """\n
    Writing START TIME: """  + str(start_writing_data) + """\n
    Writing END TIME: """  + str(end_writing_data) + """\n
    Writing execution time: """ + str(writing_time_execution) + """\n
    Total rows read from the excel file: """ + str(count_row) + """\n
    Total rows inserted in the SQL Server table: """ + str(count_rows_inserted)



    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP(host='mailhost.company.com', port=999)
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)       
    
except Exception as error:
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, error)
    
else:
    logging.info(f"Read and write data from excel file finished successfully.")
```

Comment: How does your failing code look like and what makes it throw an exeption?

Comment: I just change "DRIVER = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}', put 16 instead of 17 and run it.

Comment: Did you get any answers https://stackoverflow.com/users/6393927/fym